# How to test whether a statistically significant coefficient is driven by observations in certain periods in panel data?

Tags: econometrics, panel-data

I estimated a fixed effects model as follows using a unbalanced panel with 10 years of observations.

$y_{it}=\beta x_{it}+\delta_i+\gamma_t+\epsilon_{it}$

The coefficient of interest is $\beta$. I find it statistically significant. I want to further understand whether this effect is concentrated in earlier years, so I estimate the same model using the first 5 years and the second 5 years. Now $\beta$ in neither specification is statistically significant. I suspect that there is not enough statistical power to identify $\beta$ when I split the panel, but I am not sure.

Is there any way to understand whether the effect is concentrated in certain years? I am hesitant to run cross-sectional regressions by year because they do not exploit within-variation.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You could just use a dummy variable for first five years vs. last five years. The specification would take the form:
$$y_{it}= \beta x_{it}+ \alpha I(t \leq 5)x_{it}+\delta_i + \gamma_t + \epsilon_{it},$$
where $I(t \leq 5)$ is an indicator function. The added interaction term will allow you to look at whether marginal effects of $x$ differ before and after the break you mention. A simple test of whether $\alpha=0$ should help you address your question.